# Game Center is not showing scores in Leaders-board iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, game-center

I have integrated Game Center in my project, i can log in to game center and can open leadersboard but its not showing any scores . i have tried to submit score in leaderboard and it returns success but its not showing in there.

Submitting score

```
-(void)submitScore
{
    GKScore *myScoreValue = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"something"] autorelease];
    myScoreValue.value = [prefs integerForKey:@"total"];

    [myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Score Submission Failed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Score Submitted");
        } 
    }];
}
```

I have searched on this issue and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121089/ios-game-center-sandbox-leaderboards-show-no-score) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720316/ios-game-center-scores-not-showing-on-leaderboard-in-sandbox?lq=1) 
I have tried both but not working.

I am getting this on starting app.

```
<Info>: 16:39:10.550238 com.apple.AVConference: GKSConnSettings: set server: {
    "gk-cdx" = "17.173.254.218:4398";
    "gk-commnat-cohort" = "17.173.254.220:16386";
    "gk-commnat-main0" = "17.173.254.219:16384";
    "gk-commnat-main1" = "17.173.254.219:16385";
}
```

Is there anything wrong with me code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes for you

```
« Make sure leaderboard is setup in iTunesConnect with Id: something

« Login gamecenter app with testUser from same iTunesConnect account

« Try myScoreValue.value = 500 once, sometimes small values are neglected in sandbox mode.

« Confirm - Logged in to sandbox mode
```

[image]

Comment: I have setup id something in iTunes Connect and my values are always greater than 500. sometimes 30k.I have login from different account than apple account from which i have created app in iTunes Connect. does it matters. because in game center you can sign in from any id and submit your score

Comment: make sure you are on sandbox mode in Game Center

Comment: Yeah i m on the sandbox. Thanks for your answer. its working now. there was a space after ID and i couldnt see that. removed that space and its working now.

Comment: Check the sort order of the leaderboard in iTC.  Most common cause is that it's set wrong, so the "better" score isn't getting replaced.