# Gamer Center leaderboard shows no scores, and each user only has access to their own score

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, leaderboard

I'm trying to make a leaderboard in my game with Game Center. I post the high score like so:

```
GKScore *myScoreValue = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"grp.high_scores"] autorelease];
    myScoreValue.value = self.game.scoreMeter.score;

    NSLog(@"Attemping to submit score: %@", myScoreValue);

    [myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Score Submission Failed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Score Submitted");
            id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            [appDelegate displayLeaderBoard:nil];
        }

    }];
```

I see "Score Submitted" as expecting, and it brings up the Game Center leaderboard view, but it just reads "No Scores"

I know other people have said [you need at least two accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720316/ios-game-center-scores-not-showing-on-leaderboard-in-sandbox), but I've tried with three already.

For each account, the game shows up for them in the Game Center App, and when I query for the top ten scores:

```
- (void) retrieveTopTenScores
{
    GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardRequest != nil)
    {
        leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeGlobal;
        leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(1,10);
        [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error grabbing top ten: %@", error);
            }
            if (scores != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Top ten scores: %@", scores);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

each user only sees their own score.

So why is the leaderboard empty, and why is each user only seeing their own score?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it turns out you need to be signed in to game center with a developer sandbox account for it to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox can be messy sometimes, but let me ask you this. Is your `self.game.scoreMeter.score` an int?

If so, try doing this:

```
myScoreValue.value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.game.scoreMeter.score] longLongValue];
```

for setting the value of the GKScore object. Let me know if it changes anything.