# iOS: how to create multiple test users in sandbox environment having only 1 device available?

Tags: ios, testing, sandbox

I would like to create multiple test users for testing my App in a **sandbox environment**. Unfortunately I got only one device (iPod touch) from where I created a test user.

On the simulater it doesn't seem to be able to connect to GameCenter and hence I do not know how to create another users without having another device.

I need to do so because the leaderboard [won't show scores unless there are 2 or more users.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720316/ios-game-center-scores-not-showing-on-leaderboard-in-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

The simulator can connect to the Game Center. (The thing it can't do is make in-app purchases.) If you're testing your app in the sandbox you have to log into the Game Center within your app, not in the Game Center app. If you are already logged into Game Center with a normal login run the Game Center app on the simulator and log out. Then run your app and log in within your app.