# Game Center leaderboards were appearing now they are not

Tags: ios, game-center

I created a leaderboard for my iOS game, and everything was working fine literally 30 mins ago, when I hit the show leaderboard button, up came the name/score at the top of the leaderboard. I've read this

[iOS Game Center: Scores not showing on leaderboard in sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720316/ios-game-center-scores-not-showing-on-leaderboard-in-sandbox)

And there is only 1 name on the leaderboard (mine) and I'm using a sandbox mode GC account, but like I say the leaderboard was showing the scores fine, and then suddenly it stopped showing my score, the leaderboard still comes up, except it's blank, with just the rating at the top and "no items" half way down, any ideas?

Bit of extra info. My score shows fine in the actual Game Center App, just not (now) when I bring up the leaderboard actually within my game, whereas before it did.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have the same prob. Did u find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Play the game with at-least two different accounts, it requires at least two to show the leaderboard scores and names.

Comment: I read that in the other post, but why was it showing before with only 1 account (sandbox) being used?

Comment: that might be some kind of bug from apple's end,As i tested leaderboard never show scores before i test it with two different accounts

Comment: There's got to be something wrong with GC right now, as I can't even sign back in with my GC sandbox after I've signed out of it