# Leaderboard not found in unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center-leaderboard

I am trying to implementing itunes `Game Center` in my unity game but facing error `Leaderboard not found` searching from hours but haven't find any solution.
following is code snippet i am using.

```
Social.ReportScore(Scores, leaderboardID, (bool successful) =>
            {
                if (successful) Debug.Log("Successfully uploaded");
                else Debug.Log("Failed to uploaded");
            });
```

**Update**

i have `debug` `Social.localUser` it showed `1000 - Lerpz - False - Offline`.
i am using Unity 5.5.2f1 on windows 10.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8720434/3883492 could help you.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it show `ShowLeaderboardUI not implemented`